# RSpec, no such file to load when loading helpers

Tags: rspec, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app that uses RSpec2 beta 19. My application.rb and app_helpers.rb are in a directory /lib. The application obviously loads the helper module and my application runs but when I run RSpec I get an error that it is unable to located any gems required in the helper module. I am now sure how to load the application.rb without getting errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had multiple versions of rspec. I removed them and went with beta.22 and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

You might try upgrading to rspec-2.0.0.rc, and the final version should be available within a week, so I've heard.

Comment: that gives me a whole new set of errors. I will switch back to test/unit